# PHP json_encode both pretty and unescaped

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am trying to create a .txt document from a mysqli database and am succesfull like this:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$lang.'.txt');
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$jsonData = [];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ReloadedSnippets WHERE app = $app AND type=0 ORDER BY id");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $snippetId = $row['id'];

    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ReloadedTranslations WHERE fk_snipId=$snippetId AND lang='$lang' AND app=$app");
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

    $string1 = $row1["translation"];
    //$string1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$string1);
    $jsonData[$row['snippet']] = $string1;
}

$jsonString = json_encode($jsonData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $jsonString;
```

Now, my issue it that everything is printed in one big line in my txt document! I would like to use JSON_PRETTY_PRINT but how do I do that when I also need to use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Like this: `json_encode($jsonData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`. If you look in [the manual for json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), you see an example with multiple options under Example #2.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Perfect... Thanks :-)